# Need to change Windows NTFS File ID

Tags: python-exec

fsutil file queryfileid hkh
File ID is 0x0000000000000000001e000000001249
can anybody help me , how i can change File ID in Windows system ?
example : 0x0000000000000000001e000000001249 =0x0000000000000000001e00000000a2b1

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot arbitrarily change a file ID.  On Windows, a file is uniquely identified by the serial number of the containing volume and the file id.  In a sense, the file ID acts as the 'primary key' for a file and changing the it would lead to possible data corruption.

Generation of the file id is filesystem specific and on some filesystems it may relate to the physical layout of the file on disk.

If you copy a file to the same volume, the copy will be guaranteed to have a different file ID.